# Removing self-imposed community wiki

Tags: support

How can I get community wiki removed from an answer I submitted? The intention was never to make the answer community wiki but the checkbox is very close to the post button on mobile and I checked it accidentally whilst posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a moderator can do this on StackExchange. You need to flag your post for moderator attention and a team member will remove it for you.

Until we have pro-tempore moderators, the stack exchange team members act as moderators. After that, however, the community is given the tools to moderate.